# Node setTimeout notWorking

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

```
function work(){
    //do some of the heavy computation now
    process.nextTick(work);
}

work();


console.log("started");
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("hi there");}, 1000);
```

When I run his code I get : started, but I never get the message hi there.
Am I doing something wrong, or is this an issue with node?

Edit:
   When I replace the process.nextTick with setTimeout it works, but nextTick is supposed to be faster, or when I replace setTimeout with process.nextTick() hello shows but it doesn't wait 1000ms.

Comment: `work` is called infinitely?

Comment: why is then console.log("started") called

Comment: It's getting time to execute before the `nextTick`.

Comment: I think async functions (from the event loop) can not be called between ticks? So the `setTimeout` callback will never be called.

Comment: All IO functions won't execute I read in the specs, includes timers, so is there something other than nextTick with the same capability but doesn't block the eventloop and similar speed.

Comment: your code is too abstract to provide any meaningful answer - the `work/nextTick(work)` is pointless

Comment: it's only to simulate a function that does a lot of work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**using setImmediate is the way to go**

```
function work(){
    setImmediate(work);
}

work();


console.log("started");
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("hi there");}, 1000);
```

Comment: The solution is not bad, it's just every computer will have a different maxTick and it's not optimal for every user to use it.

Comment: yay, that's more what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js works with an event loop, (simplistically speaking) it will run any code until it returns and then run the next thing in its queue. `process.nextTick()` sets the function you pass it to be the next thing in that queue. `setTimeout(foo, x)` will tell it to add the function you pass to the queue in `x` milliseconds.

Your code is adding `work` as the next thing in the queue then finishing, so then node runs the `work` function, which does something then adds `work` as the next thing in the queue, this continues forever. At some point the timer ends and it adds your log to the queue, but since `nextTick` is always adding `work` as the first thing in the queue, it never actually pick it up.

Comment: then can you add it at the end, without using setTimout